# Unable to access locust on web-UI using docker

Tags: python, docker, port, host, locust

I have installed locust inside docker, i mapped docker port as well but when I run locust command I get below error, I am able to run locust on command line but not on Web-ui, may be i may miss-understood which host or port should use while accessing.

COMMAND:
`locust -f locustfile.py`

Error:

> oserror errno 97 address family not supported by protocol

Command:
`locust -f locustfile.py --web-host=localhost`

Result:

> [2019-12-18 11:24:47,101] ABZ-218/INFO/locust.main: Starting web
>   monitor at http://localhost:8089
>
> [2019-12-18 11:24:47,102] ABZ-218/INFO/locust.main: Starting Locust 0.13.2

but not able to access it on browser.

I have mapped port `0.0.0.0:8089`->`80`
so which command should i use while hitting locust and which command should i use while accessing it from chrome browser?

Comment: Can you share your Docker files?

Answer (score 1):

`--web-host=localhost` is not needed, by default locust will listen on all interfaces. Try removing it and seeing if that helps.

Comment: Hi, as I already mentioned in the que, simply giving COMMAND: locust -f locustfile.py shows below error:

Error:

oserror errno 97 address family not supported by protocol

Comment: I'm so sorry, I misread your question and the steps that you had tried. Are you using the locustio/locust image or one you have built yourself? A little googling indicated that the "oserror errno 97..." error could be related to having only ipv6 support. Maybe try disabling ipv6.

Comment: Btw, if you bind to localhost inside a docker container it will not be reachable from the outside. locust needs to bind to the "real" interface inside the container (typically eth0) for the port to be exposed outside of docker (this explains why --web-host=localhost doesnt work)

Answer (score 0):

You can find the IP Address of where your application is running and pass that as an argument to `--host` e.g. `--host http://127.0.0.1:8000`.

Answer (score 0):

Just for future visitors landing on this page: if you are using `docker compose run` (not `up`) to run your locust instance from Docker, the web interface might not be accessible because of port mapping.

When clarifying the difference between `run` and `up` commands, [`docker compose run`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/compose_run/) docs state:

> The second difference is that the `docker compose run` command **does not create any of the ports specified in the service configuration**. This prevents port collisions with already-open ports. If you do want the service’s ports to be created and mapped to the host, specify the `--service-ports`

So to start the locust web UI using docker, use one of the two:

```bash
docker compose up
docker compose run --service-ports <service-name> <command>
```